# Hive column as a subquery select

Tags: hive

I'm trying to do something like below with Hive.  How can I have a column in Hive be defined as a subquery?  Is this possible in Hive?

```
hive -e "           
select
distinct i.SearchListingID,
(select count(*) 
    from calls c 
    where c.ServiceID = i.SearchListingID
    ) as CallsCount
from Impressions i
where i.yyyymmdd = 20120401
limit 10" > ImpressionCalls.txt

Hive history file=/tmp/jd/hive_job_log_jd_201205222049_550931420.txt
```

> FAILED: Parse Error: line 4:1 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'count' '(' in expression specification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correlated subqueries are not supported in Hive. 
How about something like this instead? (I didn't get a chance to verify this query on Hive myself)

```
select
    i.SearchListingID,
    count(*)
from
    (
    select
         distinct i.SearchListingID as SearchListingID 
    from 
        Impressions i
    where
        i.yyyymmdd = 20120401
    )i
    join
    calls c
    on(c.ServiceID = i.SearchListingID)
limit 10
```

Comment: Thank you!  You got me on the right track.  I had to add a "group by i.SearchListingID" clause to get it to work.