# Get all rows with a matching field in a different row in the same table

Tags: sql, hive, impala

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
|id|userID|email         |website    |
--------------------------------------
|1 |user1 |user1@test.com|website.com|
|2 |user2 |user2@test.com|website.com|
|3 |user3 |user3@test.com|website.com|
|4 |user1 |user1@test.com|foo.com    |
|5 |user2 |user2@test.com|foo.com    |
```

And I want to get all of the rows where website='website.com' and have a corresponding row with a matching userID where website='foo.com'

So, in this instance it would return rows 1 and 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user you can do

```
select userID
from your_table
where website in ('website.com', 'foo.com')
group by userID
having count(distinct website) = 2
```

but if you need the complete row then do

```
select * from your_table
where userID in
(
   select userID
   from your_table
   where website in ('website.com', 'foo.com')
   group by userID
   having count(distinct website) = 2
)
```

Comment: That seems to be working perfectly! Is there any way I can get all of the columns from the rows that match instead of just userID?

Comment: @JGibel: Yes, it is the second query in my answer.

Comment: That seems to work for standard SQL, unfortunately impala doesn't support subqueries in in clauses. I'll post another question to try and address this, thanks!

Comment: I did, but I had similar issues. I did find a way to fix it though!
For anyone looking at this, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710075/hive-column-as-a-subquery-select
Thanks, @juergen d

Comment: For reference: as mentioned in my answer, subqueries in Hive are only allowed in the FROM clause. The second query in this answer is thus perfectly valid sql, but won't work in Impala or Hive. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.website = 'website.com' and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.userId = t.userId and t2.website = 'foo.com');
```

EDIT:

You can also express this as a join:

```
select distinct t.*
from t join
     t2
     on t2.userId = t.userId and
        t.website = 'website.com' and
        t2.website = 'foo.com';
```

If you know there are not duplicates, then you can remove the `distinct`.

Comment: As far as I am aware, neither Hive nor Impale support the `exists` clause. This is perfectly valid sql, but won't work in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Hive is kinda limited in terms of using subqueries (they [are only allowed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) in the `FROM` clause), so we'll have to work around that a bit. The good news is that we don't really have to worry (much) about doing massive joins, because, well, Hadoop. :-)

One way to find matching rows in a table is to simply join the table on itself.

```
SELECT left.*
FROM your_table left
JOIN your_table right
ON (left.userID = right.userID)
WHERE left.website = 'website.com'
AND right.website = 'foo.com';
```

Note we have two versions of the same table, called `left` and `right` respectively, and we are retrieving rows from `left` that have a matching row in `right` that has the same userID (`JOIN` condition) but website is foo.com (`and` clause).

Hope that helps.