# View count rows as columns in query result

Tags: hadoop, hive

First thing first: I am able to get the data one way. My purpose is to increase the readability of my query result. I am seeking if it is possible.

I have a table that fed by devices. I want to get the number of data sent on each hour that was grouped by two identical columns. Grouping these two columns is needed to determine one device type.
Table structure is like:

```
| identifier-1 | identifier-2 | day        | hour | data_name | data_value |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-----------|------------|
|  type_1      | subType_4    | 2016-08-25 | 0    | Key-30    | 4342       |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-----------|------------|
|  type_3      | subType_2    | 2016-08-25 | 0    | Key-50    | 96         |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-----------|------------|
|  type_6      | subType_2    | 2016-08-25 | 1    | Key-44    | 324        |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-----------|------------|
|  type_2      | subType_1    | 2016-08-25 | 1    | Key-26    | 225        |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-----------|------------|
```

I'm going to use one specific data_name which was sent by all devices, and getting the count of this data_name will give me the data sent on each hour. It is possible to get the number in 24 rows as grouping by identifier-1,identifier-2, day and hour. However, they will repeat for each device type.

```
| identifier-1 | identifier-2 | day        | hour | count |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
|  type_6      | subType_2    | 2016-08-25 | 0    |  340  |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
|  type_6      | subType_2    | 2016-08-25 | 1    |  340  |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
|  type_1      | subType_4    | 2016-08-25 | 0    |  32   |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
|  type_1      | subType_4    | 2016-08-25 | 1    |  30   |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
|--------------|--------------|------------|------|-------|
```

I want to view the result like this:

```
| identifier-1 | identifier-2 | day        | count_of_0 | count_of_1 |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------------|------------|
|  type_6      | subType_2    | 2016-08-25 | 340        |  340       |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------------|------------|
|  type_1      | subType_4    | 2016-08-25 | 32         |  30        |
|--------------|--------------|------------|------------|------------|
|--------------|--------------|------------|------------|------------|
```

In SQL, it is possible to get subqueries and columns in result but it is not possible on Hive. I guess it is called correlated subqueries.

[Hive column as a subquery select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710075/hive-column-as-a-subquery-select)
Answer of this question did not work for me.

Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select identifier1, identifier2, day,
       sum(case when hour = 0 then data_value else 0 end) as cnt_0,
       sum(case when hour = 1 then data_value else 0 end) as cnt_1
from t
where data_name = ??
group by identifier1, identifier2, day
order by identifier1, identifier2, day
```

Comment: This gave me the exact view I wanted. Thanks again :-)